# Ways to prevent smoke when grilling

Tags: grilling

I've been grilling hamburgers and steaks but my neighbors complain about the smoke. Are there ways to reduce the smoke but still let me cook basically the same way?

I'm currently using a Weber Kettle. I'd be willing to consider buying something new if it could keep the smoke down somehow. Currently using briquettes. Have been told lump might less smoke but wondering if it's enough.

Do any smokeless grills exist? Something with a short chimney+fan+filter? Or are there other solutions? Switching to electric or propane seems meh as no flavor.

Comment: Are you smoking stuff or just grilling up burgers or something? And whats your fuel source/setup?

Comment: updated the question to just cover grilling

Comment: Are you cooking with the lid on?    That should not produce much smoke.  Not cheap but Big Green Egg.

Comment: Is fat dropping on the coals and smoking up or what?

Comment: Share with the neighbor to get them to stop complaining?  (Sorry, its a Monday).

Comment: A drip tray to catch fat might help, or indirect heat (following on from @Batman's comment).

Answer (score 1):

Using actual charcoal rather than briquettes will make much less smoke, particularly the more objectionable "coal" smoke from getting the briquettes burnt far enough that they are useable.

In my personal experience actual charcoal lights (to a usable state) faster and if you have a good tight grill can be put out by sealing the grill for re-use, much more effectively than briquettes. If your grill is no longer tight you can put it out with water, then dry it, and re-use it.

You'll still get *some* smoke from burning fats dripping off the meat. But proper charcoal is effectively smokeless, itself.